# Move an icon on google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I've searched for similar questions here but none of them helped me. 
I have an application running on the map that shows the path taken by the user and an icon in the form of "police". What I want now is that this icon to move the map behind me. So I created a method (stalk) that calculates a new point given the current position of the user, the position of the icon and the map. The method works, but the problem is that when I run my application icon only moves once, because his position is not updated.

Here's part of my code:

```
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
    longi = String.valueOf(longitude);

    posCurrent = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    posAtuais.add(posCurrent);

    posInicial = posAtuais.get(0);
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posInicial));

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posCurrent, 19));

    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(mudaLinhaCor(heart_rate)).geodesic(true);
    for (int z = 0; z < posAtuais.size(); z++) {
        LatLng point = posAtuais.get(z);
        options.add(point);
    }
    line = map.addPolyline(options);

    LatLng posPolice = stalk(posCurrent, POLICE, map);
    Marker init = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posPolice)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.police)));


}

    //A method that computes a new position
public LatLng stalk(LatLng player,LatLng police,GoogleMap mapView){
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection(); 
    Point pointInicial = new Point(); //police
    pointInicial = projection.toScreenLocation(police);
    Point pointFinal = new Point(); //player
    pointFinal = projection.toScreenLocation(player);
    double y=0.2;
    int x=0;

    if((pointInicial.x==pointFinal.x)){
        y=pointInicial.y+1;
    }else{
        double m=(pointFinal.y-pointInicial.y)/(pointFinal.x-pointInicial.x);
        double b=pointInicial.y-(m*pointInicial.x);
        int i=1;

        while(y != (int)y){
            if(pointInicial.x<pointFinal.x){
                x=pointInicial.x+i;
                //System.out.println("entrou no x<xfnal: "+x);
            }
            else if(pointInicial.x>pointFinal.x){
                //System.out.println("entrou no x>xfnal");
                x=pointInicial.x-i;
            }
            y=m*x+b;
            //System.out.println("y: : "+y);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return projection.fromScreenLocation(new Point(x, (int) y)); 
}
```

Someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Implement OnMarkerDragListener in your activity then

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
}
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
    myMap.clear();
    latLng = arg0.getPosition();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


}
```

Comment: I have to call onMarkerDragStart and onMarkerDragEnd in onMyLocationChange?? I don't understand very well what this does...